# Imagem destacada Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, template

Olá! Estou com o seguinte problema, estou construindo um tema e a página onde os posts são adicionados não é o index.php, para que os posts aparecessem eu tive que colocar `<?php query_posts(''); ?>` no loop, ai funcionou normalmente, mas a funcionalidade (Imagem destacada) que existe no painel ADM, sumiu, mas quando eu ativo algum outro tema padrão do wordpress, essa opção aparece novamente. Alguma solução? Obrigado!

`/* ativa post thumbnails e especifica padrão para tamanho de imagem */
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('690x300', 690, 300, True);`

Comment: query_posts() nunca, nunca, conserta nada. Te juro. Vai por mim, ou pela documentação oficial: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/. Abra outra pergunta com o problema que vc tinha antes, que certamente vai ser mais fácil de resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu loop, você deverá chamar a função `the_post_thumbnail_url()`. Ela te retorna o `url` da imagem destacada do post atual. [Aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) na documentação você poderá ver mais sobre essa função e suas variações.

Um exemplo simples de uso da função:

```
<div class="blog-post">
    <div>
        <figure>
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>">
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: já estou usando `the_post_thumbnail_url();` no loop.php, e `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` no function.php, só que, o que desapareceu foi a opção **(Imagem destacada)** no painel de administração, só porque não estou mais chamando os posts na página principal e sim em uma `blog.php` nos temas padrões do wordpress essa opção não desaparece. Imagem: (http://cdn4.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/setting-featured-image.png)

Comment: Entendi! Você já olhou nas opções de tela, se a 'Imagem destacada' está setada pra mostrar?

Comment: Sim, já olhei, é só colocar outro tema qualquer que os posts estejam sendo chamados na `index.php` que volta aparecer.

Comment: Poderia postar na pergunta os códigos que vc inseriu no `functions.php`?